# Debug build on Android cannot login with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I'm having problems logging in to Facebook using a debug build of my app. I'm getting the following message:

> com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 404 [message]: Key
>   hash #Njdfu775hgnSFDvh487hrfn3un47nc= does not match any stored key
>   hashes. (404) [extra]: null

When I sign the build with my own release key and produce a signed build (debug or release), everything seems to be working just fine.

Comment: just add key Njdfu775hgnSFDvh487hrfn3un47nc= to your facebook app from developer's account

Comment: Ok it makes sense now - new mac means new internal debug keystore in android studio and it requires a different hash. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the key to your face book app and publish the app to production . Hence you can use FB users login. Else you can create sandbox accounts for doing the testing.